# Populating dropdownlist on pageload event

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I can't see why this is not working.

I have a dropdownlist named ddlRoomName and a SQL table named roomlist.

When i run the SQL command in SQL editor it works fine. But when I load the page the rooms do not load!

Am i missing something obvious here?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack Then

        ddlRoomName.Items.Clear()
        ddlRoomName.Items.Add(New ListItem("--Select Room--", ""))
        ddlRoomName.AppendDataBoundItems = True

        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("a_cisco").ConnectionString
        Dim strQuery As String = "Select * from roomlist"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery
        cmd.Connection = con

        Try
            con.Open()
            ddlRoomName.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            ddlRoomName.DataTextField = "RoomName"
            ddlRoomName.DataValueField = "intRoom"
            ddlRoomName.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            con.Close()

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Have you checked your column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only loading them on a postback. Is it really what you want? Maybe you want:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

End If
```

(then the `ViewState` will keep the items in the `DropDownList` in a postback)

Comment: wow thanks guess i need some sleep figured i was over looking something really obvious